# Converting a Text File into a Pyplot

Tags: python, text, matplotlib

I have a really long text file that I want to plot in Python. I've imported the text file using this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.figure()
with open('6-18-2015 14.2.9.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        line = [float(line)]
        plt.plot(line)
```

Every time I run the code, I get: ValueError: invalid literal for float():
How do I solve this problem? Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: We have no idea how you can solve this problem unless we know what's causing the error. If it finds something that cannot be converted to a float, like "1.23 ", it will throw an error.

do a try/except for the float and add a print repr(line) if the exception is triggered.

Chances are the line endings may be a good place to start. Each line will still have a line ending.

Comment: It will help if you can show a part of the data file you are trying to plot.

Comment: My data is basically 4x10000 array of data from a DAQ. Most of the numbers are in scientific notation. If I use the print line function, I can print the data just fine, but I can't plot the data in a pyplot.

Comment: Cool we get its large. Show something under 50 lines that reproduces the error or we can't help.

Comment: It's a bit like telling us the line doesn't quack. Cool, it's not a duck, but without seeing it, we've narrowed it from infinity to infinity.

Comment: This is a bit of the first line of the text file I'm trying to get plotted:

Comment: 1.561223360000000334e-04, 1.603947440000000454e-04, 1.451361440000000489e-04, 1.225534160000000357e-04, 1.249947920000000503e-04, 1.494085520000000339e-04, 1.433051120000000244e-04, 1.567326800000000235e-04, 1.506292400000000683e-04, 1.347602960000000545e-04, 1.597844000000000553e-04, 1.396430480000000296e-04, 1.982360720000000552e-04, 1.585637120000000480e-04, 1.378120160000000593e-04, 1.573430240000000678e-04, 1.524602720000000386e-04, 1.268258240000000748e-04, 1.335396080000000743e-04, 1.445258000000000588e-04, 1.079051600000000563e-04, 1.549016480000000532e-04,

Comment: Nevermind, I used the np.transpose to switch the rows and columns and used np.loadtxt to load my data. That made it work.

Answer (score 3):

You should have a look at [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/). It makes such tasks really trivial. For example: assuming you have a `.csv` file named `data.csv` which looks like this

```
x, y
1, 1
2, 4
3, 9
...
```

then you can plot it as follows

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_csv("data.csv")

plt.plot(df.x, df.y)
plt.show()
```

**EDIT:**

You can transpose your 4x10000 data and change it to 10000x4. Here's an example showing how to plot the 10000x4 data using matplotlib.

*4ddata.csv*

```
x,y,z,u
10.39, 73.32, 2.02, 28.26
11.13, 68.71, 1.86, 27.83
12.71, 74.27, 1.89, 28.26
11.46, 91.06, 1.63, 28.26
11.72, 85.38, 1.51, 28.26
13.39, 78.68, 1.89, 28.26
13.02, 68.02, 2.01, 28.26
12.08, 64.37, 2.18, 28.26
11.58, 60.71, 2.28, 28.26
8.94, 65.67, 1.92, 27.04
11.61, 59.57, 2.32, 27.52
19.06, 74.49, 1.69, 63.35
17.52, 73.62, 1.73, 63.51
19.52, 71.52, 1.79, 63.51
18.76, 67.55, 1.86, 63.51
19.84, 53.34, 2.3, 63.51
20.19, 59.82, 1.97, 63.51
17.43, 57.89, 2.05, 63.38
17.9, 59.95, 1.89, 63.51
18.97, 57.84, 2, 63.51
19.22, 57.74, 2.05, 63.51
17.55, 55.66, 1.99, 63.51
19.22, 101.31, 6.76, 94.29
19.41, 99.47, 6.07, 94.15
18.99, 94.01, 7.32, 94.08
19.88, 103.57, 6.98, 94.58
19.08, 95.38, 5.66, 94.14
20.36, 100.43, 6.13, 94.47
20.13, 98.78, 7.37, 94.47
20.36, 89.36, 8.79, 94.71
20.96, 84.48, 8.33, 94.01
21.02, 83.97, 6.78, 94.72
19.6, 95.64, 6.56, 94.57
```

*plot.py*

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

df = pd.read_csv("4ddata.csv")

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.scatter(df.x, df.y, df.z, s=df.u)
plt.show()
```

This example represents the 4th dimension as (point size)<sup>2</sup>

[image]

As you have a very long file, you may want to use

```
ax.scatter(df.x, df.y, df.z, c=df.u)
```

instead of

```
ax.scatter(df.x, df.y, df.z, s=df.u)
```

This will represent 4th dimension as color thus preventing unnecessary visual clutter.

[image]

The problem in you case is that when you use `for line in f:` you are reading the entire line. So you get something like

```
line = "1.23, 4.26, 5.78, 3.44\n"
```

Python is unable to figure out how to convert this variable to float and hence the error. The invalid literal here is probably a `,`. Also, using a loop to iterate through data to plot is likely to be highly inefficient, you must use the provided functions where ever possible as they are highly optimized for the task they perform.